# NRWL Storybook with Angular: Replace Doc page

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

I am using NRWL with Angular and storybook. I am wondering if there is any way to replace default Docs page with a custom README.md file.

I have been trying to replace Docs page with a .mdx file as well but not successful yet.

This is how i am trying to override default Docs page from within my-component.stories.ts file

```
export default {
  title: 'MyComponent',
  component: MyComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MaterialModule
      ],
    })
  ],
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      page: './MyComponent.stories.mdx',
    },
  },  
} as Meta<MyComponent>;
```

[image]